# SSO between 3 different Spring Web applications

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

Here is my situation:

1. Data Webapp: it's a third party webapp which shows to users some relevant data restricted by roles. It is developed using Spring but it uses tomcat digest for security and gets users and roles from a jndi resource. Nevertheless, I have the sourcecode and I can implement Spring Security on that.
2. Users & Roles manager Webapp:  it's mine and manages a DB which contains users, roles, etc. It is developed in Spring (MVC, Security and so on). The DB is exposed as jndi resource in tomcat and the other apps takes the necessary data from that resource. I created this app because I want to be as less invasive as possible in #1.
3. REST service Webapp: it's mine and I use token auth in this one. Users sends user/password and credentials are verified getting the data from the jndi resource. It returns a valid token.

In #2 I have two types of authentication through the Spring form (User/password and Openid)

The first thing I came up with the #2 app could be like a CAS server because I use this only to add users, edit, set roles, remove groups,... but I don't know if makes sense having real implementations.

The second one is to deploy a real CAS server but I don't know if it is too much for two or three apps. I've read some posts about CAS, SAML, OAUTH2... but I have a little mixture..

Could you help me to decide which option is the most suitable? I want to share the same login page, to be able to log in through rest and not to see the login page each time I switch between the apps.

Thank you